# tensor product of two representations of simple lie algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I encountered a statement in a book:

> Another important property of the tensor product of representations of *simple* Lie Algebras is that the tensor product of two irreducible representations $R$ and $R'$ contains the singlet, i.e. the trivial one-dimensional representation, at most once as a submodule.

Subsequently, it says

> it does contain the singlet precisely in the case when $R'$ is the representation $R^+(g):=-(R(g))^t$ conjugate to $R$.

How to understand and prove these statements?

Comment: You want to compute $\text{Hom}(1, V \otimes W)$ where $V, W$ are irreducible (and finite-dimensional). This is the same as $\text{Hom}(V^{\ast}, W)$, so by Schur's lemma has dimension $0$ if $V^{\ast}$ is not isomorphic to $W$ and $1$ if it is (assuming we're working over $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, Thanks for your comment. But I am not clear about the meaning of the notation $Hom(1, V\otimes W)$ here.

Comment: $\text{Hom}(A, B)$ is the vector space of morphisms of representations / intertwining operators from $A$ to $B$. $1$ is the trivial representation. $V \otimes W$ is the tensor product. $\dim \text{Hom}(1, A)$ counts the number of times $1$ occurs as a subrepresentation of $A$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Your argument is very enlightening. But can you show that $\textrm{Hom}(1, V\otimes W)=\textrm{Hom}(V^*, W)$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I now know how to show it. Thanks.